# Problem with asynchronous programming in node.js and mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm currently working on the URL shortener project from freecodecamp.org for the backend and API course.
I'm having some kind of problem with this piece of code:

```
app.post('/api/shorturl', async (req, res, next) => {

  let url = req.body.url;
  let urlObj;

  try {

    urlObj = new URL(req.body.url);

  } catch (err) {

    req.err = err;
    return next();

  }

  let hostname = urlObj.hostname;

  try {

    console.log("TENTATIVO URL " + url);
    const address = await dns.promises.lookup(hostname);
    saveUrl(url).then(() => {
      console.log("url " + url);
      Url.findOne({ url: url }).exec().then(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data.get('shortUrl'));
          res.json({ original_url: url, short_url: data.get('shortUrl') });
        }
      );

    });


  } catch (err) {

    req.err = err;
    next();

  }
},
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.err);
    res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
  });
```

When I try to `console.log` the `Url.findOne` query result sometimes the `shortUrl` field is shown and sometimes it is not.
All the documents are correctly saved in the MongoDB database, I just can't understand why sometimes the query partially fails.

Here's an example of the log:

[image]

and the here's the document saved in the MongoDB database:

[image]

this is the saveUrl definition:

```
const saveUrl = async (originalUrl) => {

  let u = new Url(
    {
      url: originalUrl
    }
  );

  u.save();

};
```

Comment: Check all documents in the collection if the `shortUrl` exists in all documents.

Comment: What is saveUrl definition?

Comment: I *strongly* recommend not mixing traditional promise handling using `.then` with `async/await`. If your query throws your `try/catch` will not catch it the way you've structured your code. Your callback is *already* `async`, just `await` the calls to `saveUrl` and `Url.findOne` instead of trying to nest callbacks.

Comment: @l2ysho I've edited the post with the saveUrl definition

Comment: @LinDu yes, shortUrl exists in all documents

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you, I'll rewrite the function following your suggestions

Comment: found the problem, in the saveUrl function, I wasn't awaiting `u.save()`, so the `Url.find()` query was sometimes executed before the document was actually saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In saveUrl function you do not return `u.save()` so you are dangling a promise in this way, thats why sometimes you see result and sometimes dont, you do not wait for execution is done.

```
const saveUrl = async (originalUrl) => {

 let u = new Url(
   {
     url: originalUrl
   }
 );

 return u.save();

};
```

or more neat way because there is no need to have async function if you don't use await in it.

```
const saveUrl = (url) => new Url({url}).save()
```

Some adjustments to your original code

```
app.post('/api/shorturl', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const original_url = req.body.url
    const urlObj = new URL(original_url)

    const { hostname } = urlObj
    console.log('TENTATIVO URL ' + url)
    const address = await dns.promises.lookup(hostname)
    const url = await saveUrl(req.body.url)  

    console.log('url ' + url)
    const data = await Url.findOne({ url: url }).exec()
    console.log(data)
    const short_url = data.get('shortUrl')
    console.log(short_url)

    return res.json({ original_url, short_url })
  } catch (err) {
   req.err = err
   next()
  }
 },
(req, res) => {
  console.log(req.err)
  res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' })
  },
)
```